# Assign a callback return value to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I'm really struggling here. I am using the nifty evenIfHidden plugin and it works fine in jQuery functions that expect a callback, which properly returns the width or height value. But if I just want to assign that value, I get back a jQuery object, really annoying.

This works perfectly:

```
$(this).text($(this).evenIfHidden(function(e) {
                                      return e.width();
                                  })
);
```

This does not:

```
var width = $(this).evenIfHidden(function(e) {
                                      return e.width();
                                 });
```

Instead of assigning e.width() to `width` it assigns the jQuery object, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin does not return anything, declare a local variable which will be assigned within the callback via a closure.

```
var width = "";
$(this).evenIfHidden(function(e){
    width = e.width();
});
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much! JavaScript really works in mysterious ways... So instead of returning in the function I should just assign, how neat.

Comment: You're welcome. But how is the local width variable available within the function scope?

Comment: Short Version:  In this case the variable will be on the global scope, which gets added to the scope chain of the anonymous function.  I'm assuming your code is within some other function, in this case a closure is created.  Long Version(Worth Reading): http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. If the `evenIfHidden` function doesn't return a value there's not much you could do. Instead you should consume this value inside the callback because that's the only place this value is available. You should not be attempting to flow it outside. So for example if you wanted to perform some action with this width, instead of trying to pass it as return value to the `evenIfHidden` function you could use it inside the callback:

```
$(this).text(
    $(this).evenIfHidden(function(e) {
        var width = e.width();
        // do something with the width here, for example you could pass it to some other function
        someFunction(width);
        return width;
    })
);
```